# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_toLeftof' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Why would I be getting this error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        ...

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_spent1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/groc_store"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:hint="-"
            android:inputType="number"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftof="@+id/text_spent1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/groc_store"
            android:text="Spent: $"
            />

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I've also tried `android:layout_toRightof` but I get the same error message for the `layout_toRightof` attribute. I also tried just using `"@id/text_spent1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_spent1"
```

Capital "O"

[RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_toLeftOf)